# Одновременное выполнение нескольких команд

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

Запускаю одновременно от 10 до 20 php-скриптов следующим sh-скриптом:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    php /home/user1/script.php 1 & 
    php /home/user1/script.php 2 &
    ...
    php /home/user1/script.php 19 &
    php /home/user1/script.php 20;
```

Как изменить код таким образом, чтобы задать эти команды  в цикле с параметром N (количество одновременно запускаемых на выполнение экземпляров скриптов), который можно периодически вручную менять?

Извиняюсь за неточные формулировки.

Comment: Использовать цикл for?

Comment: Запуск фоновых задач в баше сломан, используйте более подходящие инструменты для таких целей, например ninja.

Comment: Может быть сформировать в цикле строку команд, а потом ее запустить? или что-то подобное, чтобы не расписывать вручную все одинаковые 20 комманд с разными параметрами.

Comment: @user7860670, `Запуск фоновых задач в баше сломан` — хм. а разработчики bash в курсе этой проблемы?